# Error in enbling SR-IOV with Ubuntu 18.04 on Intel ixgbe - Intel X550 - Dell R640

Tags: virtualization, dell-poweredge, intel, ubuntu-18.04, sr-iov

I'm having issues on creating VF with ubuntu 18.04.
SR-IOV is enabled from BIOS, the NIC are Intel X550, I added 
`intel_iommu=on` to `/etc/default/grub` and also tried using modprobe.d
by adding `options ixgbe max_vfs=8` on `/etc/modprobe.d/ixgbe.conf`

But if I check using `lspci | grep -i ethernet` I only get the physical cards.
I have also tried:

```
# echo '7' > /sys/class/net/eno1/device/sriov_numvfs
bash: /sys/class/net/eno1/device/sriov_numvfs: Permission denied
```

Is the configuration correct?

From dmesg I get:

```
$ dmesg | grep iov
[  137.321216] ixgbe 0000:19:00.0 0000:19:00.0 (uninitialized): Failed to enable PCI sriov: -38
[  138.295030] ixgbe 0000:19:00.1 0000:19:00.1 (uninitialized): Failed to enable PCI sriov: -38
[  139.263114] ixgbe 0000:1a:00.0 0000:1a:00.0 (uninitialized): Failed to enable PCI sriov: -38
[  140.227147] ixgbe 0000:1a:00.1 0000:1a:00.1 (uninitialized): Failed to enable PCI sriov: -38
```

If may be usedfull here you can find the [dmesg | grep iommu](https://pastebin.com/byLHq77w) 
and the full [dmesg](https://pastebin.com/uV2jeq8v)

Many thanks.
Gabriele

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this, was a lack of documentation from Dell side.
I had to enable also SR-IOV for each NIC, in the Device Settigs from the System Configuration, the global enabler is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the correct kernel module: *"ixgbevf"* loaded? Check with `lsmod`

If not you can do so manually `modprobe -i ixgbevf` and make that persistent by adding a line containing that module to `/etc/modules`

Comment: Thanks, I enabled the module (and also made it persistent), but still got the same error. I cannot even see the vfs related file in the sysfs.
if I try `# echo 4 > /sys/class/net/eno1/device/sriov_numvfs
-bash: /sys/class/net/eno1/device/sriov_numvfs: Permission denied`

Same problem with error -38 if I use `modprobe -i ixgbe max_vfs=4`